# Send midi note on/note off with velocity over wifi from iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, midi, out, coremidi

Does anyone have example with iOS/Objective C, on how to send midi "note on/note off" signal (with different velocity) over wifi so that iPad would  display in "Mac OS X->Audio Midi Setup->Network. then I click connect device" and by simple touching on the button on iPad code will send midi command. I believe I need to use some protocol,but I'm newbie on this, please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the coremidi framework (provided by the IOS). See here for a introduction: http://www.synthtopia.com/content/2011/06/02/coremidi-brain-dump/

Comment: But how to support it with Bonjour to share MIDI information over a network. ? Can you please show me code example. Thanks

Comment: +1, best resource out there for Core MIDI. @user1195202 don't be lazy, read the link (specifically, the pages at SyntheticBits that it links to) that Kris gave you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you find an answer helpful, you should accept it. Please [read about accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: the synthtopia blog link is now private.

Comment: archive.org is your friend... https://web.archive.org/web/20120306005143/http://syntheticbits.com/blog/?p=508

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking I wrote sample code that is on GITHUB that wirelessly sends/receives MIDI notes ON/OFF messages from iPhone/iPad to Windows PC, Apple Mac or any other device listening. Full instruction on GITHUB.

see: https://github.com/JohnGoodstadt/MidiNotes